# how to make Listview change content(array) and onitemclick function

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

```
final String[] genre = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f","g","h","i","j" };
final String[] genre1 = {"...","0","1","2"};
final String[] genre2 = {"...","3","4","5"};
static int listint = 0;

...

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {        

  if(position==0) {                
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate
   (R.layout.pager_item_test, container, false);   
    container.addView(view); 
    ListView ListViewOnScreen = (ListView)container.findViewById(R.id.ListViewOnScreen);        

      if (listint == 0) {            
        ArrayAdapter arrayadaptermain = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, genre);
        ListViewOnScreen.setAdapter(arrayadaptermain);
        ListViewOnScreen.setOnItemClickListener(onitemclicklistenermain);

      } else if (listint == 1) { 
       ArrayAdapter arrayadapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, genre1);
        ListViewOnScreen.setAdapter(arrayadapter1);
        ListViewOnScreen.setOnItemClickListener(onitemclicklistener1);}


       return view;
}

...

}


public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onitemclicklistenermain = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l_position) { 
     String tv = (String)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tv + " printed from main, listint = " + listint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


     switch(position){   
        case 0:  listint = 1;  break;               
 }}};


public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onitemclicklistener1 = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 
   @Override        
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,                                    long l_position) {   
     String tv = (String)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);  
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tv + " printed from 1, listint = " +  listint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

     switch(position){                    
        case 0: listint = 0; break;
 }}};`
```

this is part of the SlidingTabsBasicFragment (from SlidingTabsBasic) whose page is listview.

I'm trying to make this program like this:

-At first, ListViewOnScreen shows String[] genre.

-When ListViewOnScreen is showing String[] genre, clicking the position 0 ("a") will make ListViewOnScreen show String[] genre1 instead.

-When ListViewOnScreen is showing String[] genre1, clicking the position 0 (here, it would be "...") will make ListViewOnScreen show String[] genre again.

I thought that this code would work. But the ListViewOnScreen shows genre (not genre1) consistently no matter what the listint is.

Ex) Clicking 'a' first time: 
    Toast: a printed from main, listint = 0
    No change in array, still showing "a","b",...

```
Clicking 'a' second time:
Toast: a printed from main, listint = 1
Still No change in array.
```

How should I change my code in order to work properly?

Comment: Did you try calling arrayadaptermin.notifyDataSetChanged(); after you make changes to your adapter to refresh the listView

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as comment but I dont have the necessary credits to post, so I am adding this as an answer.From the code that you have posted here it seems like you are working on the  PageAdapter instantiateItem function. Well, from the output one can make out that the instantiateItem function is called just once for the page which sets up your initial adapter which has the contents genre[] and displays them. The next time you press "a" the page is being reused instead of being created fresh and so the instantiateitem function is not being called again. So, probably instantiateItem is not the place to switch adapters ?